# Executing commands using expect4j

Tags: java, tcl, expect

I'm using this [Code Example](http://nikunjp.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/remote-ssh-using-jsch-with-expect4j/), to execute commands in Tcl shell .

If you look at the main function down the page , the way of executing commands is :

```
 SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient("linux_host", "root", "password");
 List<String> cmdsToExecute = new ArrayList<String>();
 cmdsToExecute.add("ls");
 cmdsToExecute.add("pwd");
 cmdsToExecute.add("mkdir testdir");
 String outputLog = ssh.execute(cmdsToExecute);
```

In my program I'm doing :

```
 SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient("linux_host", "root", "password");
 List<String> cmdsToExecute = new ArrayList<String>();
 cmdsToExecute.add("bpsh"); // open Tcl Shell
 cmdsToExecute.add("set bps [bps::connect ... ]"); // Tcl shell commands
 String outputLog = ssh.execute(cmdsToExecute);
```

Now the problem is that i can't execute commands from arrayList without exiting the Tcl Shell .
meaning if i run this Code :

```
 SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient("linux_host", "root", "password");
 List<String> cmdsToExecute = new ArrayList<String>();
 cmdsToExecute.add("bpsh"); // open Tcl Shell
 cmdsToExecute.add("set bps [bps::connect ... ]"); // Tcl shell commands
 String outputLog = ssh.execute(cmdsToExecute);
 cmdsToExecute.clear();
 cmdsToExecute.add("set sf [$bps createSuperflow ... ]"); 
 String outputLog = ssh.execute(cmdsToExecute);
```

i get that after the first execute on the remote machine it exited the first tcl shell and went back to original shell , and in the second execute it tries to run :
 "set sf [$bps createSuperflow ... "  in the original shell .
i assume because the line :
  cmdsToExecute.add("bpsh");
doesn't exist .

The Code of the expect4j that i'm using is in the link above , can someone tell me what i need to modify so that i can execute many commands using ssh.execute() without it exiting the Tcl shell ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build a file with the list of commands and source it.

Something like...

```
cmdsToExecute.add("echo \"\" > tmpcmd.txt");
cmdsToExecute.add("echo \"set bps [bps::connect ... ]\" >> tmpcmd.txt");
cmdsToExecute.add("echo \"set sf [$bps createSuperflow ... ]\" >> tmpcmd.txt");
cmdsToExecute.add("bpsh");
cmdsToExecute.add("source tmpcmd.txt");
```